# Python script not creating enough output lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, mutex

I need to write 1,000,000 random numbers to a single file using multiprocessing in Python and take note of how it affects execution time. For some reason, whenever I run the script I am only ending up with 997,716 numbers.

Here's my code:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

mutex = Lock()

def task1():
    for i in range(500000):
        mutex.acquire()
        f.write(str(random.randint(0,1000)) + "\n")
        mutex.release()
       
def task2():
    for i in range(500000):
        mutex.acquire()
        f.write(str(random.randint(0,1000)) + "\n")
        mutex.release()

start = time.time()

f = open("file2.txt","a")
       
p1 = Process(target = task1, args = ())
p2 = Process(target = task2, args = ())

p1.start()
p2.start()

end = time.time()

print('Execution Time: {}'.format(end-start))
```

Comment: [This](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBBCsIwEEVxm1MMxUUCVRQ3Uugd3EsXRZM6miYhGamexY0bPZSnMTVWdOHfzfvJn-Ff7u5MO2uu19uR1GT5GI2Vty20R03ovN3IENA0gK2znmCVCGNbqYDqcOCiYBClrAcENOBr00g-n0W9rV7OoyGOOSjUslSCsQ5pB9ZJw7OeTelEWQ5ZlwmoA6j01UE5rORU-0ZS2S8VyZyGyIgP096i4X-Sv0M1GhlisMZAPJ6SbtPx_csRH9JP62JR_YLJoqhEKuvd2dDdEw) is how I'd demonstrate it. See [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each process has its own in-memory buffer for the file (as python buffers IO), you need to explicitly flush those buffers to disk inside the lock if you want to be sure no race conditions happens.

```py
def task1():
    for i in range(500000):
        mutex.acquire()
        f.write(str(random.randint(0,1000)) + "\n")
        f.flush()
        mutex.release()
```

flushing is a slow function, so you may want to have only 1 process doing all the writing to disk and other processes sending things to write through a [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

---

#### Fork BUG

there's currently a bug in Cpython, when using `fork` (which is the default `process` creation on linux) the forked children never garbage collect the global scope, so your file is not flushed at the end of the child's function, and some data written to the file may be lost.

a solution to this is to either

1. `.close()` or `.flush()` the file descriptor at the end of the worker function.
2. make the `open("filename",'w')` call inside the child process instead of the parent. (first close the file descriptor in the child if it was already open in the parent)

this won't solve the synchronization problem between the workers, it will just make sure they don't terminate before they flush their internal buffers.

Comment: Where can I read about this own in-memory buffer? And does it not even flush when the process finishes?

Comment: @KellyBundy the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module explains some of how this works, but the rest you'd get from reading python's [pyio](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_pyio.py) module source code, basically python doesn't write directly to the OS's buffers on a file write (or `print`), it first writes it to an internal buffer, which is later written to the OS's buffer when it is full,  also when `f` object is deleted a `flush()` is triggered.  same as on read where it reads a chunk of the file to a buffer, and each call to `read` will return a part of it.

Comment: Yes, I know about the buffering in general, I'm just unfamiliar with `Process`, that's what I'm asking about. Does it not flush when the process finishes? In my own demo (link under the question) I used only one thread, I joined it, I used `with open`, and it still didn't flush. I also added `p.close()`, `del p`, `gc.collect()`, and slept a few seconds, but nothing did the job, always lines missing. I'm wondering whether I just didn't properly finish the process, or whether a process really doesn't flush its stuff when it finishes.

Comment: @KellyBundy seems like a bug in cpython that happens when a file handle is forked, the `__del__` is never called on the file handle when it is deleted, so you manually have to close the handle `f.close()` or `f.flush()` it, seems like there's a [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0446/) for other problems that are caused by that, that was never implemented.

Comment: @KellyBundy so the current implementation of python calls [`os._exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) instead of `os.exit()` so no garbage collection happens when the child finishes its function other than the one that would happen by the termination of the function itself, so global objects aren't garbage collected by the child.

Comment: Ah yes, I had also tried `exit()` in the process function, and now tried `sys.exit()` (`os.exit()` doesn't exist) there as well. Didn't help, either.

Comment: @KellyBundy a `sys.exit()` won't help because it will raise an Exception (that's how it tries to do GC) which will be caught and `os._exit()` will be called instead, the only 2 options are to either `.close()` the file descriptor or to `.flush()` it.